# Weird distortion in face of mesh

Tags: texturing, uv, distort

In this face of my mesh, I can see that there is in UV map leading to ugly material. The lines start out straight but quickly become a curved mess. [image]

This is weird because my UV editor says that there is no stretching in that area at least:
[image]

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Hello :). Do you use any modifiers on the model?

Comment: maybe try to unwrap again with Project From View?

Comment: @JachymMichal No

Comment: I think that distortion could come from the additional vertices at the on side, I'm not sure how your model is made, but I could imagine, that one of the other Islands is scaled different and I would bet the distortin happens at these vertices, try moving one of them and see if something changes.

Comment: Can you attach simplified blend? It seems more the distortion is at green part or faces wasnt unwrapped anymore, but if your sure with selection ... Do you have a more UV maps?